# close ons-sliding-menu on clicking main-page

Tags: onsen-ui

```
<ons-sliding-menu var="slidingMenu" main-page="index.html" menu-page="menu.html" max-slide-distance="200px" type="overlay" side="left" swipable ="true"></ons-sliding-menu>
```

My sliding menu structure is above. The slide menu is working fine like opening and closing, on clicking the Button.

**But my issue is, need to close the sliding menu on clicking outside of menu or on clicking the main-page(index.html)**

I would like to know, is there an option available or any work around is available.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it would be nice to close the menu by clicking outside.

You can use the `'postopen'` event for the Sliding Menu to attach a click handler to the main page. In the click handler you can call `slidingMenu.close()`. It's also important to remove the click handler, otherwise you won't we able to open the menu again.

Code:

```js
ons.ready(function() {
  slidingMenu.on('postopen', function() {
    var main = slidingMenu._element[0].
      querySelector('.onsen-sliding-menu__above').children[0],
        el = angular.element(main);

    el.on('click', function() {
      slidingMenu.close();
      el.off('click');
    })
  });
});
```

The following pen shows how it can be used:
http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/jENKeX

Since it's a nice behavior I think it will be added in the next version.

Regards